# c program to run process as background and never dies?

Tags: c, linux, api, timer, timertask

```
int daemon()
{
if (daemon(1, 1) < 0) /* Keep the same working directory and pipes */
{


             makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
             makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
             makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
    return 1;
              }
    }




 int main()
{
daemon();
}


           return 0;

         }
```

I created a timer and the timer is calling the task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. I want to run the timer in the background and it should never die. Could anyone give me some ideas in c program to run the task in the background for linux operating system.
I want to make this three calls to run in the back ground :

```
   makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
   makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
   makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `daemon()` function in C from `unistd.h`. It makes it easy to detach yourself from the terminal and run in the background.

It's as simple as

```
if (daemon(1, 1) < 0) /* Keep the same working directory and pipes */
{
     perror("daemon");
     return 1;
}
```

and just put that in your `main` function

Comment: thank you very much. i edited my code and want to run the three function calls in the background. So could you please tell me how to do that ??

Comment: At the start of your program, presumably your `main()` just call the `daemon()` function. Read the man page for it if you need more info. The function takes care of calling `fork()` and changing your I/O pipes for you and detaches you from the parent process.

Comment: I am telling the truth and have to submit my project by tomorrow. so could you PLEASE help me ?? else they will fail me.

Comment: shall i put the above three funtion calls in a single function name as daemon and call that from main function ??  I edited my code : shall i do like above ?

Comment: @user3340661 The whole process becomes a `daemon` you do not need to change your code other than just placing those lines of code mentioned as the first lines in `main`.

Comment: I want to run those three function calls in the background. I created a timer to call for every 2ms task, 10ms task and 100ms task. how to do that ?? I did not get you.

Comment: @user3340661 I'm pretty sure the `timer_create` calls have already set up the timer and from a quick glance it looks like you set up your handler correctly so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: if there is a handler then it is not necessary to use daemon ?? The below link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017825/how-to-run-the-function-in-parallel   //in debug mode : i am able to call the task1 and after that it is not calling task2 and task3. Could you please help me ?

Comment: @user3340661 That's because you're using `recvfrom()` which is blocking. You may be better off creating a new question and picking your words more carefully as the original question is asking how to run a background process. You probably should have stated how to create threads or something to that effect.

Comment: I tried ioctl api for non blocking then also it doesn't work.  if i use pthread_create for a fucntion but how to do it for recvfrom api ??

Comment: @user3340661 After your code edit your code no longer makes any sense unfortunately. This comment thread is also getting a little long. You should create a new question with some better wording as to your exact problem which rather than being spawning background processes is actually related to threading.

Answer (score 0):

You could call your script using the nohup command. Simply run your script on the command line as follows `nohup <myscript>`

It may be what you really want is to create a cron job, however. Check docs for your linux distro to find out more.

Comment: `nohup` is best when running things over ssh. If the OP wants to just run in the background `daemon` is the better option.